# Github in Visual Studio - add existing project

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I'm trying to put an existing project under Git source control but I'm unclear on a few things.

My professor set up a private repository for my team, and as far as I know,I should go inside the newly created repository and copy the clone URL. However, when I open the new repo there is nothing. No option to branch, pull requests, url, nothing. How do i upload an existing VS project to this repo?

Comment: http://imgur.com/apGyaTM This is what i see

Answer (score 4):

- Go to **File > Add to Source Control** and choose **Git** on the dialog window
- Enter a commit message on the Team Explorer Window, then commit and push
- It will ask for the repo url, just paste it

Comment: But where do i find the repo url? on github's website i dont see it

Comment: If you can't find it, url of repository is like: https://github.com/nameofaccount/nameofrepository.git